# Rails 4 asset pipeline, config.assets.debug and AJAX

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, will-paginate

I'm trying to use the ajax_paginate gem with will_paginate and it works perfectly in development when:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

... in development.rb. However, in Production or when:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

... in developement.rb the ajax functionality is completely borked. Does anyone have suggestions about what I can do? I've tried running rake assets:precompile, that did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean assets with rake assets:clean and run the assets:precompile

also look for errors on console of you web browser or on sever log.